# VBA Excel Selenium- Use browser address bar for small temporary notes

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Good afternoon everyone,

Does anyone know how to put text in the Selenium Chrome Driver address bar that will serve as notes to select the best option without having to change the window looking for these notes?

[example of intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZQS1.jpg)

```
   Private gc As New Selenium.ChromeDriver

   Sub NotesInAdressBar()
   Dim ks As Selenium.Keys
   
   Set ks = New Selenium.Keys

    gc.AddArgument "start-maximized"
    gc.Start
    gc.Get "https://www.google.com"
    

end sub
```

I Try gc.Get "I want to put the notes here for temporary consultation!" but gives error [PIC Err](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D_0N4tUaC5e6wlk98l8_nqgYclwpDZFn/view)

**solved it like this:**
(...)

```vb
    'previous code...
    Call Application.SendKeys("^{e}", True)
    Call Application.SendKeys("I want to put the notes here for temporary consultation!", True)
```

[PIC result...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlm9x.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Dim bot As WebDriver  'global keeps the Chrome window open...

Sub Test()
    Set bot = New Selenium.WebDriver
    bot.Start "chrome", "https://www.google.com"
    bot.Get "data:text/html,<h1>Read Me</h1>Some text here.<br>And here."
End Sub
```

Comment: That was not what I intended. This will change the page I'm viewing. I solved it like this: `Call Application.SendKeys("^{e}", True)`
`Call Application.SendKeys("I want to put the notes here for temporary consultation!", True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass the desired text i.e. *`I want to put the notes here for temporary consultation!`* to ***`Get`*** as follows:

```
bot.Get "I want to put the notes here for temporary consultation!"
```

Comment: added to the code posted above `gc.Get "I want to put the notes here for temporary consultation!"` there was an error [pic err](http://example.com)https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D_0N4tUaC5e6wlk98l8_nqgYclwpDZFn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: On accessing `https://www.vodafone.pt/pacotes/cobertura/` I'm seeing [Access Denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXseA.png)

Comment: because the page is only available in Portugal. Would you have to use a VPN from Portugal

Comment: I'm afraid. I don't think so.

Comment: lol...so I don't know. It doesn't matter the page, that's not the point... =)